# yii2 GridView how to change column?

Tags: yii2

```
echo \yii\grid\GridView::widget(
        [
            /**
             * Экземпляр класса, который реализует \yii\data\DataProviderInterface. В нашем случае ActiveDataProvider
             */
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
                'ip',
                'date',
                'request',
                [
                    'attribute' => 'ip',
                    'value' => function ($data) {
                        return long2ip($data['ip']);
                    }
                ]
            ],

        ]
    );
```

ip changes, but date and request disappear, how to fix it
ip changes, but date and request disappear, how to fix it

Comment: Hi, I can't understand what you need, Are you looking for set custom value for columns?

Comment: Returns 3 fields ip, date, request.
I need to change the ip values when outputting.

Answer (score -1):

So, just change this part:

```
'columns' => [
            [
                'attribute' => 'ip',
                'value' => function ($data) {
                    return long2ip($data['ip']);
                }
            ]
            'date',
            'request',
        ],
```

you just duplication one elment of array, and now you can use it.